# How do you calculate camera extrinsics of top left quarter of an image?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I have the intrinsics (`I`) and extrinsics (`E`) of a camera and the corresponding undistorted image.

I would like to construct a synthetic camera (extrinsics and intrinsics) that corresponds to the top left quadrant of the original image.

I guess the new intrinsics (`I'`) would be the same with the focal length multiplied by 2.0.

Is it possible to compute the extrinsics (`E'`) of this new synthetic camera?

[image]

Comment: My first guess is that the shift should be proportional to the shift in pixel converted in the normalized camera frame (`Z=1` using original `fx` and `fy`). You should get a 3D coordinate (x,y,Z=1). To get the true shift, I think that you should then multipliy by the the distance to the focal plane in meter. So probably you will need the sensor size in meter or a way to get `fx` in meter?